# No "Place Windows" option in CCSM?

Tags: unity, compiz

I can't find the place windows option in CCSM. Do I have to download something?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

EDIT:

Solved. Found it by Typing "place" in the search bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have it under "Window Management" with (that I know of) no extra installs, only CCSM. Found it by typing "place" in the search window. (Not much of an answer if you are actually missing it, but I know that sometimes I miss things like this because I'm looking in some other place so can't hurt :)).

Comment: Found it by searching for "place". Thanks :) *facepalm*

Comment: @lyingfisch: I was thinking you must have been missing something :P